# Copy /home successfully from old disk to new computer running Debian

Tags: linux, debian, rsync

I've read answers to similar questions, but I don't yet see answers to what I'm curious about.  I've read much of the rsync man page, and I want be sure I understand what I'm doing before I make too much extra work for myself.

I have a disk from a computer that died.  It was running Debian Oldstable.  I now have a machine running Debian Stable (Stretch), and I'd like to move `/home` across without breaking anything.  I've got the old disk in a dock, and the new `/home` is empty except for config files created when I installed Debian and one folder on my desktop where I've put a few files I have had to create so far.

I think rsync is the best answer, but I see potential in cp, too.

Would this sequence of commands and actions work?

```
<mount disk OLD via the doc>
su
rsync -a -v -z -H -A -X --update -P --logfile=/tmp/rsynclog.txt /media/OLD/home/ /home
exit
<unmount disk OLD>
```

I would try this first with `-n` to see what it thinks of this process.  I might also start by copying `/media/OLD/home/user1/` `/home/user1` so I've less to redo if something strange happens.

I know I can combine short options; I separated them here for ease of viewing and discussion.

`-a` should preserve times, owner, and group by name, right?  I don't know what it will do if it finds a group on OLD that hasn't been created on NEW yet; I hope it creates the group on NEW.

I'm not sure if `-z` helps or hurts.  I've got a USB3 connection from the old disk, so I should probably just skip it.

I'm doing `AHX` just in case.  I can't remember if I created a hardlink at some time on OLD, I don't think but can't guarantee that ACLS don't exist, and I don't yet understand extended attributes.  Is it true this won't hurt if they don't pertain to my directory?

I've got a number of config files that Debian Stretch created.  Is it true that `--update` will prevent those from being overwritten with no other side effects?  Then I can do a diff later to see if I need to think about making changes.  (Is there a way to prepare for that diff?)

And I think but am rarely 100% sure that I specified the files such that I should end up with a `/home` on NEW that mimics `/home` on OLD except possibly for a few config file changes because of newer versions of Debian packages.

Do you see anything that I missed or that will get me in trouble here?

@xenoid: I appreciate that suggestion.  That's why I used the --update option, so it (presumably) wouldn't overwrite any dot files that Stretch had just written on my machine.  I figure that's a lot like doing a Linux dist-upgrade, taking the new config files always, and patching up problems, if any, later.

For reference, here's the command I used for each user defined on my system:

```
su
rsync -avHAX --update -P --log-file=/tmp/rsynclog.txt /media/OLDpartition/username/ /home/username
exit
```

So far, it seems to have worked.  I'd accept an answer, since I think we all basically said the same thing, except there really aren't answers--more confirmations of pieces of the direction I was headed.

Comment: User and group are just numbers; i.e., numeric attributes of files.  ``cp -a`` and ``rsync -a`` will copy them even if they don’t currently have names on the system, but they will not “create” them by entering them into ``/etc/passwd`` and/or ``/etc/group``.

Comment: @Scott: yes, user and group are numbers, but my understanding is that rsync will match by name, if it can, and then probably by number if it can't.  Isn't --numeric-ids the option to force rysnc to ignore names and just map by number?

Comment: Have you considered just adding the old disk to the new computer and having /home span both disks?

Comment: @mcalex: Not really.  The new disk is more than big enough, there is AFAIK no second bay in my new laptop, and I'm using an external dock, not a case.  Am I missing something?

Comment: ahh, laptop.  Nope, i was missing something.

Comment: I moved between Ubuntu machines several times and I don't copy the whole /home blindly, because there is the odd chance that some new version of the software doesn't expect the old file format. I copy all my data (`~/Documents` and others) but I'm more cautious with the dotted directories. I let the software create its own (Firefox, Thunderbird, Chrome...), rename it, and copy the one from the previous machine. If everything is OK (often the case) then fine. But I usually redo the desktop stuff in the new machine (icons, shortcuts, etc.), I have had problems using old configs on new versions).